# NodeMCU not responding AT after blink app

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, wifi, nodemcu

I've just bought NodeMCU LoLin ESP8266, I tried to send AT commands (after spending days on ESP8266-01) and everything was okay. Than I've uploaded the Blink example to the board, after that moment it's not responding to any command.

I tried to update firmware, it's updating successfully but nothing has changed. By the way blink app is not working also...

Comment: the Blink program replaced the AT program

Comment: @Juraj How can I put it back?

Comment: download the AT firmware binary from Espressif site. On Windows you can use Espressif Flash Download Tool to flash it. On Linux use esptool.py. https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14

Comment: Done, thanks! Can you add this as an answer, people who has the same problem may see it easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replaced AT firmware in esp8266 with Blink and you want it back, download the AT firmware from [Espressif download page](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/at?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14) and flash it with the [Espressif Flash Download Tool](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools) (Windows) or with [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool).